# Building and Deploying a Static Web Page Using Azure DevOps Pipeline (Excluding Release Pipeline)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-deployment

I'm attempting to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps to both build and deploy a static web page. I've managed to build and publish the artifacts using the following pipeline configuration:

```html
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Publish Build Artifacts
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: './app/public'
    ArtifactName: 'website'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}
    KeyVaultName: 'xx-keyvault'
    SecretsFilter: 'XX-XX-XX'
    
- script: |
    # Set the secret value as an environment variable
    export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(XX-XX-XX)

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'website'
    downloadPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifacts
    
- script: |
    az storage blob upload-batch --destination XXX --source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifacts
  displayName: 'Upload to Azure Storage'
  env:
    AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: $(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
```

However, after publishing the build artifacts, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with the deployment process. I've already implemented a similar flow using an Azure DevOps release pipeline, but now I want to achieve the same result within the same pipeline. Any suggestions or guidance on how to continue from this point would be greatly appreciated.

**The primary goal is to deploy the static web to azure storage account without relying on the Azure DevOps release pipeline. Thank you in advance for your assistance!**

Comment: On what resource do you host your static app?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the AZ CLI script, use a AzureFileCopy@4 task

e.g

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    SourcePath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifacts/*
    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: myFileStorage
    ContainerName: 'myContainer001'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-file-copy-v4?view=azure-pipelines